# Change the color of autofill for Stripe payment with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

We are using Stripe's Element payment feature with NextJS.
Only the part of [this link](https://github.com/stripe-samples/nextjs-typescript-react-stripe-js) that is relevant to element payments is taken out and used.

I use

```
.StripeElement--webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #2E365630 !important;
}
```

this code([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895436/stripe-elements-given-code-dont-show-the-custom-payment-form)) to change the background color when I fill in the number in the auto-complete function when using a credit card, but it doesn't change.

I'm not sure how relevant this is, but

```
const CARD_OPTIONS = {
  iconStyle: 'solid' as const,
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#FFFFFF',
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      backgroundColor: '#2E365630',
      fontWeight: '500',
      fontFamily: 'Roboto, Open Sans, Segoe UI, sans-serif',
      fontSize: process.browser ? (window.innerWidth < 480 ? "16px" : "20px") : "16px",//'16px',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      ':-webkit-autofill': {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#FFFFFF80',
      },
    },
    invalid: {
      iconColor: '#ef2961',
      color: '#ef2961',
    },
  },
};
```

this is the card options.

I couldn't find an explanation of the option to change the background of autofill in the official documentation (there was one for text color), if you don't mind me asking.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe documents [how to set styles in Elements for pseudo-classes in the Stripe.js reference](https://stripe.com/docs/js/appendix/style).

In fact, you're already using that method in the code you have above to set the foreground color:

```js
      ':-webkit-autofill': {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
      },
```

If you want that to set the background color as well you add it like any other property:

```js
      ':-webkit-autofill': {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        backgroundColor: '#2E365630',
      },
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
However, the background remains white.
This may be due to the fact that backgroundColor is supposed to work only for selection pseudo-classes.

If you have any other knowledge, please share it with us.

Comment: Ah, [apparently autofill is special and you can't change the background color without using a workaround that involves `box-shadow`](https://dev.to/atndesign/a-trick-to-change-the-autocomplete-background-color-21ll).  Stripe.js' API doesn't allow you to set `box-shadow`, so I think this isn't possible unfortunately.  Sorry about the misunderstanding!